# c#.net draw a rectangle from another method

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

my code is

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tabPage2.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(tabPage2_Paint);     
}
```

---

```
private void tabPage2_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow,new RectangleF(10,210,450,30));
}
```

---

now i have another method that do the measurements and these measures need to pass and draw a new rectangle on tabPage2 .....i am confused how to do this..... (i am new in graphics)

```
public void func()
{
     long a = 10;
     long b = 210;
     long c = 30;
     long d = 30;  

     // now how to do new 'new RectangleF(a,b,c,d)'
}
```

Comment: Pass the graphic object as a parameter to your function `func(Graphics g)`

Comment: actually the func() does some calculation and now it needs to call for drawing....(inside the func()) some thing like e.graphics.draw........ inside the func()

Comment: Then you should have the class raise an event and have the form listen for that event.  Invalidate the TabPage when the event is called.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void func()
{
     int a = 10;
     int b = 210;
     int c = 30;
     int d = 30;  

     // now how to do new 'new RectangleF(a,b,c,d)'
     drawFunc(a,b,c,d)
}

public void drawFunc(int aa,int bb,int cc,int dd)
{
     IntPtr tab = tabPage2.Handle;
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(tab);

     g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Navy, new Rectangle(aa, bb, cc, dd));
}
```